# Problem: Fehler in model.frame.default(formula = surv_mCRC ~ timing_6, data = list( : Variablenlängen sind unterschiedlich)

Tags: r

I am new in R, mainly try to plot survival curves with ggsurvplot. Now I want to plot several curves in a row with ggsurvplot_by_group but get the error mentioned above.

Follwing details:

```
str(dat_mCRC_df)
'data.frame':   592 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ center      : chr  "OKL" "OKL" "OKL" "OKL" ...
 $ ED_num      : num  39874 39988 40183 40190 40191 ...
 $ sex         : chr  "männlich" "männlich" "weiblich" "männlich" ...
 $ age         : num  79 61 83 78 73 76 63 66 48 71 ...
 $ alive_death : num  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mOS_m       : num  0 43 102 16 27 43 31 1 15 28 ...
 $ DFS_m       : num  30 43 17 16 0 33 13 0 8 0 ...
 $ dUICC_num   : chr  "3" "3" "2A" "3B" ...
 $ Lokalisation: chr  "Zäkum" "Flexura lienalis" "Colon ascendens" "Sigma" ...
 $ left_right  : chr  "right" "left" "right" "left" ...
 $ rectum_colon: chr  "Colon" "Colon" "Colon" "Colon" ...
 $ timing_6    : chr  "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" ...
 $ timing_3    : chr  "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" ...
 $ timing_12   : chr  "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" "metachron" ...
 $ met_res     : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ mHEP_only   : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mHEP_PUL    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ mPUL_only   : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mOTHER      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RAS         : chr  "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "RAS-wt" ...
 $ BRAF        : chr  "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" ...
 $ MMR         : chr  "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" ...
 $ met_loc     : chr  "PUL_only" "including LYM" "HEP_only" "including LYM" ...
 $ sex_num     : num  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
```

than

```
>surv_mCRC <- Surv(dat_mCRC_df$mOS_m, dat_mCRC_df$alive_death)

>fit_mCRC_all <- survfit(surv_mCRC~sex_num, data = dat_mCRC_df)

>ggsurvplot_group_by(fit_mCRC_all,dat_mCRC_df, group.by = "met_res",
                          palette = "lancet")
```

this results in:

```
Fehler in model.frame.default(formula = surv_mCRC ~ sex_num, data = list( : 
  Variablenlängen sind unterschiedlich (gefunden für 'sex_num')
```

which is `

```
error in model.frame.default(formula = surv_mCRC ~ sex_num, data = list( :variable 
               lengths differ (found for 'sex_num')`
```

Possibly very easy for the most of you....
Thanks for your help, regards

Comment: I don't have any experience with the `survival` package, but according to its documentation, `Surv` returns "An object of class Surv". You use this object (in your example: `surv_mCRC `) directly in the `survfit` function (`surv_mCRC~sex_num`). Maybe you can't do that (it expects a vector/list something with same length as `sex_num`)

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, this doesn't solve the problem.....tried this:

Comment: I tried this:
```
fit_mCRC_all <- survfit(Surv(dat_mCRC_df$mOS_m, dat_mCRC_df$alive_death)~sex_num, data = dat_mCRC_df)

ggsurvplot_group_by(fit_mCRC_all,dat_mCRC_df, group.by = "met_res",
                          palette = "lancet")
```

Comment: finally solved it, you were right Dario, Surv-function is different to and does not accept the matrix-input but only the variable name without the dataframe before (ie not "dat_mCRC_dfmOS_m" but "mOS_m"). Thank you again!